# jest - Pass JSON files as arguments to jest script

Tags: node.js, json, npm, jestjs, command-line-interface

My code is expected to be run as

```
node index.js conf/config1.json conf/config2.json
```

I am writing tests to validate

```
conf/config1.json` and `conf/config2.json
```

I was hoping to do something like

```
npm test -- conf/config1.json conf/config2.json
```

Where in `package.json`, `scripts.test` points to `jest`.

This does not work; it fails with this error:

```
testRegex:  - 0 matches
```

In other words, with the above command, `jest` looks for test files in the `conf` folder.

**`test/args.test.js`**:

```js
const { describe, test, expect, toBe } = require('@jest/globals')

describe('Configuration checks', () => {

  describe('CLI arguments check', () => {
    test('CLI arguments are exactly two in number', () => {
    // Write expect code here
    })

    test('Configuration file parameter is an existing file', () => {
      // Write expect code here
    })

    test('Configuration file parameter allows reading', () => {
      // Write expect code here
    })
  })
})
```